# NGINX - Is there an Nginx command to see an expanded nginx config file / directive list

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

My Nginx config consists of lot of nested nginx config files. Is there a way / command that can help me see the final / expanded directive list.

Comment: Use: `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: @RichardSmith : You misunderstood, what OP is asking. OP does not want a print-out of all referenced config file, he wants an "expanded view": A view, where the include-lines in the config are replaced with the actual contents of the include-file.